# Connection string for SQLite with Entity Framework code-first approach

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, connection-string, system.data.sqlite

The connection string I'm using doesn't work.

I'm using SQLite & Entity Framework in a code-first approach. I downloaded System.Data.SQLite from NuGet.

Is code-first approach of Entity Framework supported by SQLite database?

App config connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="LaptopContext" connectionString="Data Source = C:\Users\anila\Documents\SampleDemo1.db; Version = 3;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Add-Migration command doesn't work.

Error message: Keyword not supported: 'data source'.

What connection string should I use?

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/msallin/SQLiteCodeFirst#how-to-use)

Comment: @alejandrozuleta Still getting the error message: Keyword not supported: 'data source'. I set target as .net 4.5.2 and installed SQLite.CodeFirst.

Comment: After making few changes to App.Config file, I'm getting following error:

No MigrationSqlGenerator found for provider 'System.Data.SQLite'. Use the SetSqlGenerator method in the target migrations configuration class to register additional SQL generators.